# how to get the user array only tried everything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, native

this is my json object i got from node.js i want to get the users array to set my state .. i treid everything but i will get *poyo* width the array

```
{count: 2, users: Array(2)}
count: 2
users: Array(2)
0: {_id: "5cdd1c260d0b3d0660d85bfc", name: "Punith", email: "puntihdd@gmail.com", request: {…}}
1: {_id: "5cdd1c4d0d0b3d0660d85bfd", name: "Ashwith", email: "ashwith@gmail.com", request: {…}}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

i want to get

```
[
    {
       _id: ,
       name: ,
       email: ,
    }
]
```

in this order

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: How are you currently trying to access it?

Comment: ```export const logIn = (email, password) => {
    console.log('loggin in');
    const res = fetch(LOGIN_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .catch(err => err);

    return res;
}```

Comment: Would you mind putting that in the body of the question?  Comments aren't a good place for code samples, since it throws away most formatting...

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, it looks like you are receiving an object from some noSQL database.
With the assumption that your object looks as the following:
`{count: 2, users: Array(2)}`, we can the obtain the users property with the following:

```
const yourObject = { count: 2, users: [{}, {}]};
const users = yourObject.users;
```

Now we have the users array, we can re-map it so that we only get the three properties (_id, name, email) like you want by using the `.map()` method:

```
//  exactly the same property names like you want:
users.map(x => ({ _id: x._id, name: x.name, email: x.email }));

//  or omitting the underscore on your new items to make it nicer:
users.map(x => ({ id: x._id, name: x.name, email: x.email }));
```

Bundling these concepts, here's a working example that might help you:

```js
const myData = {
    count: 2,
    users: [{
            _id: "5cdd1c260d0b3d0660d85bfc",
            name: "Punith",
            email: "puntihdd@gmail.com",
            request: {
                a: 'value'
            }
        },
        {
            _id: "5cdd1c4d0d0b3d0660d85bfd",
            name: "Ashwith",
            email: "ashwith@gmail.com",
            request: {
                a: 'value'
            }
        }
    ]
}

const users = myData.users;
const formattedUsers = myData.users.map(user => ({
    _id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email
}));

console.log(formattedUsers);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can `map` the response of the Ajax request to extract certain values. But keep in mind that the order of properties inside of objects is not guaranteed. If you need the properties in order you have to return an array, but then you lose the propertyname information. Instead the values can be accessed via index 0,1,2.

```
const returnUsers = ({users}) => users.map(({_id,name,email}) => ({
     _id,name,email     
   })
```

or return an array

```
const returnUsers = ({users}) => users.map(({_id,name,email}) => ([
     _id,name,email     
   ])
```